# High-performance ClientWebSocket wrapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket, system.reactive

I'm working on a web socket client wrapper around `ClientWebSocket` and this is kinda my first public library project, which is why I'm asking this question here. I was inspired by [this](https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client) web socket client wrapper, because it uses Rx .NET instead of regular .NET events and I also wanted to give `System.IO.Pipelines` a try.

There are a few things I'm not quite certain about:

- I should probably move `ClientWebSocket` and `CancellationTokenSource`'s instantiation into the `StartAsync` method. That way people will be able to start and stop the web socket stream anytime they wish. I think it's even necessary, because with the current design, I'm not able to implement reconnect logic.
- The call to `ListenAsync` in `StartAsync` is currently blocking the UI thread. I'm not sure if that's good by design, because I saw how people did it [here](https://github.com/teraa/Tw.Net/blob/b5fd6f1ee184316a9a6a2f1eec46698ea08bf682/src/Common/Clients/WebSocketClient.cs#L64-L65). They split the write and read logic, just like Microsoft's example [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines#pipe-basic-usage). Microsoft did the same in SignalR's [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/SignalR/clients/csharp/Http.Connections.Client/src/Internal/WebSocketsTransport.cs#L201-L202).
- I think `ClientWebSocket` has to be instatiated just like they did [here](https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client/blob/master/src/Websocket.Client/WebsocketClient.cs#L64-L73) (a factory), because that way the users can take advantage of the options that ClientWebSocket provides. For ex. the proxy settings, etc.
- Perhaps a `SemaphoreSlim` would be useful between the calls in the methods. Example usage [here](https://github.com/teraa/Tw.Net/blob/b5fd6f1ee184316a9a6a2f1eec46698ea08bf682/src/Common/Clients/WebSocketClient.cs#L52).
- I'm not quite sure if I really need the second `while` loop in `ListenAsync`
- Suggestions about the logging and what I did with the `LogManager` class?

The idea of the library is high-performance (`System.IO.Pipelines`), Rx Events (`System.Reactive`), proper logging and error handling, connection lost and connection restored events (not implemented yet) and reconnection based on a specific TimeSpan (also missing). I would like to know how you guys would've done it.

```csharp
public interface IWebSocketClient : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Client identification.
    /// </summary>
    string ClientId { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Web socket state.
    /// </summary>
    WebSocketState State { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Keep alive interval (heartbeat).
    /// </summary>
    TimeSpan KeepAliveInterval { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Stream for received message (raw format).
    /// </summary>
    IObservable<string> MessageReceived { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Connects to the web socket server and starts listening for messages.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class WebSocketClient : IWebSocketClient
{
    private const int ReceiveBufferSize = 2048;

    private readonly ISubject<string> _messageReceivedSubject = new Subject<string>();
    private readonly WebSocketClientOptions _options;
    private readonly Pipe _pipe;
    private readonly ClientWebSocket _webSocket;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Whether this instance is disposed.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _isDisposed;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The log manager object.
    /// </summary>
    protected internal LogManager LogManager;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="WebSocketClient" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="options"></param>
    protected WebSocketClient(WebSocketClientOptions options)
    {
        Guard.Against.Null(options, nameof(options));

        _options = options;
        LogManager = new LogManager
        {
            Level = options.LogLevel ?? LogLevel.Information,
            Writers = options.LogWriters ?? new List<ILogger>()
        };

        _webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
        _pipe = new Pipe(new PipeOptions(useSynchronizationContext: false));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The pipe writer.
    /// </summary>
    private PipeWriter Writer => _pipe.Writer;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The pipe reader.
    /// </summary>
    private PipeReader Reader => _pipe.Reader;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public string ClientId { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IObservable<string> MessageReceived => _messageReceivedSubject.AsObservable();

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public TimeSpan KeepAliveInterval
    {
        get => _webSocket.Options.KeepAliveInterval;
        set => _webSocket.Options.KeepAliveInterval = value;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public WebSocketState State => _webSocket.State;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    async Task IWebSocketClient.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        Guard.Against.Null(_options.BaseAddress, nameof(_options.BaseAddress));

        if (State == WebSocketState.Open)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Client was already connected");

        try
        {
            await _webSocket.ConnectAsync(_options.BaseAddress, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            LogManager.Write(LogLevel.Debug, $"Socket {ClientId} connected");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is WebSocketException)
        {
            LogManager.Write(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message);
        }

        await ListenAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Factory method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IWebSocketClient Create(WebSocketClientOptions options) => new WebSocketClient(options);

    private async Task ListenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (State == WebSocketState.Open && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && !_isDisposed)
        {
            try
            {
                var bytesRead = await _webSocket
                    .ReceiveAsync(Writer.GetMemory(ReceiveBufferSize), cancellationToken)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

                // TODO: I don't think this loop is needed at all
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && !bytesRead.EndOfMessage &&
                       bytesRead.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Close && !_isDisposed)
                {
                    if (bytesRead.Count == 0)
                        break;

                    Writer.Advance(bytesRead.Count);

                    bytesRead = await _webSocket
                        .ReceiveAsync(Writer.GetMemory(ReceiveBufferSize), cancellationToken)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

                // We didn't get a complete message, we can't flush partial message.
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested || !bytesRead.EndOfMessage ||
                    bytesRead.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close || _isDisposed)
                    break;

                // Advance the EndOfMessage bytes before flushing
                Writer.Advance(bytesRead.Count);
                var flushResult = await Writer.FlushAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (flushResult.IsCompleted)
                    break;

                // TODO: Should probably be using the following template: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines#pipe-basic-usage оr https://github.com/teraa/Tw.Net/blob/b5fd6f1ee184316a9a6a2f1eec46698ea08bf682/src/Common/Clients/WebSocketClient.cs#L211
                if (bytesRead.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    ReadPipeAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is OperationCanceledException or WebSocketException
                                           or InvalidOperationException)
            {
                LogManager.Write(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message);

                break;
            }
        }

        await CompleteAsync(cancellationToken, _webSocket.CloseStatus, _webSocket.CloseStatusDescription);
    }

    private void ReadPipeAsync()
    {
        if (Reader.TryRead(out var readResult) && readResult.Buffer.Length > 0)
        {
            var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readResult.Buffer);

            Reader.AdvanceTo(readResult.Buffer.End);

            _messageReceivedSubject.OnNext(json);
        }
    }

    private async Task CompleteAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        WebSocketCloseStatus? closeStatus = default,
        string? closeStatusDescription = default)
    {
        await Reader.CompleteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await Writer.CompleteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (_options.CloseWhenCompleted || closeStatus != null)
        {
            await CloseAsync(closeStatus ?? WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, closeStatusDescription ?? string.Empty,
                cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task CloseAsync(
        WebSocketCloseStatus closeStatus,
        string closeStatusDescription,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (State is WebSocketState.Closed or WebSocketState.CloseSent or WebSocketState.Aborted)
            return;

        await _webSocket.CloseAsync(closeStatus, closeStatusDescription, cancellationToken);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Throw if disposed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    private void ThrowIfDisposed()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException($"{nameof(WebSocketClient)} has been disposed");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The standard dispose destructor.
    /// </summary>
    ~WebSocketClient()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">If this method is called by a user's code.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            _webSocket.Abort();
            _webSocket.Dispose();

            _messageReceivedSubject.OnCompleted();
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}

/// <summary>
///     Configures the behavior of <see cref="IWebSocketClient" />.
/// </summary>
public class WebSocketClientOptions
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The base address.
    /// </summary>
    public Uri? BaseAddress { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Whether to close the underlying <see cref="System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket" /> when
    ///     either the <see cref="IDuplexPipe.Input" /> or <see cref="IDuplexPipe.Output" />
    ///     is marked as completed. Defaults to <see langword="false" />.
    /// </summary>
    public bool CloseWhenCompleted { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The log level.
    /// </summary>
    public LogLevel? LogLevel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Collection of ILogger implementations to forward the message to.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<ILogger>? LogWriters { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
///     Log manager implementation.
/// </summary>
public class LogManager
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The log level.
    /// </summary>
    public LogLevel Level { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Collection of ILogger implementations to forward the message to.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<ILogger> Writers { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Write a log entry
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logLevel">The verbosity of the message</param>
    /// <param name="message">The message to log</param>
    public void Write(LogLevel logLevel, string message)
    {
        if ((int) logLevel < (int) Level)
            return;

        foreach (var writer in Writers)
        {
            try
            {
                writer.Log(logLevel, message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to write log to writer {writer.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
///     A helper class for disposables.
/// </summary>
public static class DisposableExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Ensures the provided disposable is disposed with the specified
    ///     <paramref name="collection" />
    ///     .
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the disposable.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="disposable">The disposable.</param>
    /// <param name="collection">
    ///     The collection to which
    ///     <paramref name="disposable" />
    ///     will be added.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>The disposable.</returns>
    public static T DisposeWith<T>(this T disposable, ICollection<IDisposable> collection) where T : IDisposable
    {
        Guard.Against.Null(disposable, nameof(disposable));
        Guard.Against.Null(collection, nameof(collection));

        collection.Add(disposable);
        return disposable;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static readonly ManualResetEvent ExitEvent = new(false);

    private static async Task Main()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Debug, theme: SystemConsoleTheme.Colored)
            .CreateLogger();

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomainOnProcessExit;
        AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += DefaultOnUnloading;
        Console.CancelKeyPress += ConsoleOnCancelKeyPress;

        using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { builder.AddSerilog(Log.Logger); });

        var disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

        var uri = new Uri("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/bnbusdt@trade");

        var client = WebSocketClient.Create(new WebSocketClientOptions
        {
            BaseAddress = uri,
            CloseWhenCompleted = true,
            LogLevel = LogLevel.Debug,
            LogWriters = new List<ILogger>
            {
                loggerFactory.CreateLogger<WebSocketClient>()
            }
        });

        client.MessageReceived
            .Subscribe(message => { Log.Information($"Message received: {message}"); })
            .DisposeWith(disposable);

        await client.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

        ExitEvent.WaitOne();

        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }

    private static void CurrentDomainOnProcessExit(object? sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Log.Warning("Exiting process");
        ExitEvent.Set();
    }

    private static void DefaultOnUnloading(AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
    {
        Log.Warning("Unloading process");
        ExitEvent.Set();
    }

    private static void ConsoleOnCancelKeyPress(object? sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Warning("Canceling process");
        e.Cancel = true;
        ExitEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's with `catch (Exception ex) when (ex is WebSocketException)`? Can't this just be `catch (WebSocketException ex)`?

Comment: @Reinderien, it's identical

Comment: @nop it is identical neither in C#, nor in Runtime.

Comment: have you ever completed and published your project?